# Firefox adds extra space around image in button with border

Tags: html, css, firefox, button

I have an `<img>` in a `<button>`. The button has a border. The image is scaled to 100% height and the width of the button is determined by the calculated image width. So far so good, as it works as long as there's no border on the button. If I add a border, Firefox is going to downscale the image but not to adjust to the new image width. It will simply add extra space. Chrome and Safari are doing this as expected – or at least as I expect it.

How can I get Firefox to behave the same?

**Figure**

You can see the extra green area I'm trying to get rid of.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button>
        <img src="//placehold.it/160x90">
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
}

button {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: green;
    border: 0;
    border: 3px solid tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

button img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/4tjmmq58/

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't just use `<input type="image" src="/image.png" />` rather than wrapping a image with a button?

Comment: @Aaron I thought I gain in semantics as the button should be a clickable GUI-element and not an actual input element or more specific a "*A graphical submit button*".

Answer (score 1):

That is how Firefox interprets the div tag to add the width div  but you can just change the css to be like the following:

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 170px;
}

button {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: green;
    border: 0;
    border: 3px solid tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

button img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

and this should fix the over-sized div around the button. But I would recommend using different browsers and `<tags>` when doing what your doing.

reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem as the wrapper is actually a wrapper for multiple elements not just for a single button - which would be overkill in the DOM. :) Also the width of the buttons is depening on the embedded image. I don't quite get, what you're trying to say with "*But I would recommend using different browsers and <tags> when doing what your doing.*".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `box-sizing: content-box;` to the button and your problem will be fixed but another will emerge. Now your border won't be calculated in the elements `width`/`height` so you may have to subtract it by manually.

Answer (score 0):

set images max-width and max-height:

```
.img{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100px; // your container height
    width: auto;
    max-width: 178px; // 16:9
}
```